# how to find the maximum number of times the customer id logged in consecutively

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands, self-join

table

| customer id | login |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-03-01 |
| 1 | 2016-03-02 |
| 1 | 2016-03-03 |
| 1 | 2016-03-05 |
| 1 | 2016-03-06 |
| 1 | 2016-03-07 |
| 1 | 2016-03-08 |

I want to find what is the maximum number of times the customer id logged in consecutively.

My approach is

1. Use self join to create lag (I use self join because directly using lead and lag will not work here).
2. Now somehow I need to create a column which checks if previous date is null then 0, else count 1,2,3,..... If previous date is again 0 then start counting from zero again.

| customer id | login | previous date | consecutive_day_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-03-01 | null | 0 |
| 1 | 2016-03-02 | 2016-03-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2016-03-03 | 2016-03-02 | 2 |
| 1 | 2016-03-05 | null | 0 |
| 1 | 2016-03-06 | 2016-03-05 | 1 |
| 1 | 2016-03-07 | 2016-03-06 | 2 |
| 1 | 2016-03-08 | 2016-03-08 | 3 |

-- Now I can find the max `consecutive_day_flag` and name the column as highest consecutive days.

| highest_consecutive_day |
| --- |
| 3 |

---

How can I handle the step 2 of creating a `consecutive_day_flag` column?

Or please suggest any better approach.

I have tried above approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *gaps and islands* problem. One method for solving it uses `LEAD()` to get next row, then use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `SUM()`  to generate groups :

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, login, LEAD(login, 1, login) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY login)) <= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS day_diff
  FROM mytable
),
cte2 as (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY login) 
       - SUM(day_diff) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, day_diff ORDER BY login) AS grp
  FROM cte
),
cte3 AS (
  SELECT customer_id, grp, COUNT(1) AS consecutive_day
  FROM cte2
  GROUP BY customer_id, grp
)
SELECT customer_id, MAX(consecutive_day) AS highest_consecutive_day
FROM cte3
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Result :

```
customer_id highest_consecutive_day
1           4 -- from 2016-03-05 to 2016-03-08 is 4 not 3
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/P8BCaiF1)